# JAVA Mail - Can't send email from corporate MS office network

Tags: java

Following is my code to send email from the corporate MS office email id, but I am getting the error - javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful. My username and password are correct.

```
            final String user="abc@abc.com";
            final String password = "1234";

            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            //props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp-mail.outlook.com");
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", "outlook.office365.com");
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

            Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                      new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                            return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
                        }
                      });
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse(sendEmailAddress));

            String text = "Test email";


            message.setSubject("Test email");
            message.setText(text);
            Transport.send(message);
```

Comment: According to the error, your username and/or password are incorrect.

Comment: My username and password are correct. Not sure why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.office365.com");`

Reference: [Outlook mail settings](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/POP-and-IMAP-settings-for-Outlook-Office-365-for-business-7fc677eb-2491-4cbc-8153-8e7113525f6c)

Comment: Can you include the stacktrace?